# Mysql Query does not return Results on WHERE but on AND

Tags: mysql

Here is the query i am using to join two tables

```
SELECT `rf_popup`.* 
  FROM `rf_popup` LEFT JOIN 
       `g_metadata` ON (`rf_popup`.`name` = `g_metadata`.`name`) 
 WHERE (`g_metadata`.`g_id` = '2009112305475443' AND 
        `g_metadata`.`value` < rf_popup.cardinality OR 
        `g_metadata`.`g_id` IS NULL) AND 
       `category` IN ('S', 'all') AND 
       `field` IN ('descr', 'all') AND 
       `filler_type` IN ('F2', 'all') 
 ORDER BY `rf_popup`.`priority` DESC LIMIT 5
```

THIS IS TABLE rf_popup

```
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                                                                               | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)                                                                            | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(200)                                                                       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| text         | text                                                                               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cardinality  | int(11)                                                                            | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| field        | varchar(200)                                                                       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category     | enum('A','H','N','R','S','D','all') | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| time_to_show | enum('START','END')                                                                | YES  |     | START   |                |
| filler_type  | enum('F1','F2','F3','R1','R2','R3','all')   | YES  |     | FILLER1 |                |
| priority     | int(11)                                                                            | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

This is TABLE g_metadata

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| g_id  | varchar(50)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name  | varchar(50)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

But the Query Returns Empty Result.but if i replace `WHERE` in query with `AND`. The query returns the results.Whats the difference??
There shouldn't be any difference so i am confused

Comment: You might need additional parenthesis in WHERE to make it work `((`g_metadata`.`g_id` = '2009112305475443' AND 
  `g_metadata`.`value` < rf_popup.cardinality) OR 
   `g_metadata`.`g_id` IS NULL)`

Comment: @peterm I did that but nothing happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply speaking, `WHERE` filters the *entire result set* and `JOIN ... ON` filters only the joined table.

Since you have a `LEFT JOIN` here, putting the filter in the `ON` clause restricts the results returned for the `g_metadata` table, but does not effect the results returned for `rf_popup`. That is, you will get null columns in the joined table (`g_metadata`) but the rows for `rf_popup` will still be pulled.

On the other hand, putting the filter in the `WHERE` clause performs the join first, then filters *the resulting (joined) result set*. That is, rows that do not match the entire `WHERE`clause are simply not returned.

---

Consider the following simplified examples:

```
TableA:

id
-----
1
2
3

TableB:

id   | yesNo
-----+------
1    | yes
2    | no
3    | yes
```

1. A simple join:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM TableA 
   LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.id
   ```

   returns

   ```
   A.id | B.id | yesNo
   -----+------+------
   1    | 1    | yes
   2    | 2    | no
   3    | 3    | yes
   ```
2. Filtering in the `ON` clause:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM TableA 
   LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.id
       AND yesNo = 'yes'
   ```

   returns

   ```
   A.id | B.id | yesNo
   -----+------+------
   1    | 1    | yes
   2    | NULL | NULL
   3    | 3    | yes
   ```
3. Filtering in the `WHERE` clause:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM TableA 
   LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.id
   WHERE yesNo = 'yes'
   ```

   returns

   ```
   A.id | B.id | yesNo
   -----+------+------
   1    | 1    | yes
   3    | 3    | yes
   ```